# Google App Engine Process Terminated (Error Code 123)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've seen a lot of people with this issue.

```
Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be causing this issue? I increased the instances for our project. I minimized as many database connections as possible and if a connection fails I make sure to catch it and close my connections.

Some of the request that get this error take longer than 60 seconds which I reaches the limit for App Engine standards but not all of them do. Some error at 3 - 10 seconds.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The various deadline exceeded errors are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Not all deadlines are created equal!

When a request exceeds deadline, it causes the *process* to stop, which will interrupt and cause all other requests on the same instance to fail as well.  You would see a 104 on these requests in the log viewer.

Comment: Okay. It makes sense so this must not be the issue since I am only getting 123 Errors and not 104 Errors

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some of these requests are timing out because the requests have been in the queue waiting for your application for too long. Some of these may be [loading requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/scaling#loading_requests), which you can fix by [installing a warmup handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_Warmup_requests) which loads your application before the user requests arrive.

Another possibility which could cause requests to spend a lot of time in the queue would be if you have values for [`threadsafe`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Using_concurrent_requests) (use `threadsafe: true` if you are using an asynchronous framework like Twisted or NDB) or [`max_concurrent_requests`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#automatic_scaling) which don't reflect your application's behavior. `max_concurrent_requests` should be roughly equal to (time spent responding / cpu time for response) in Python; the default value is 8, but if you have mostly synchronous requests, you might want to set it lower.

Comment: More details on loading requests here: http://bjk5.com/post/40833194761/pending-queues-and-loading-requests-on-app-engine

Comment: I read somewhere that request in a queue behind something that times out would receive the same 500 server error as the request that brings down the instance. So I think I understand your first section.

We are using warmup handlers and `threadsafe: true`. Currently we only use `max_concurrent_requests` (set at 10) for our tasks queues which are lightly used for customer emails to us (less than 200 or so a day). Is there a `max_concurrent_requests` setting I can edit for our instances?